# what does " parent directory accessors" means?

Tags: c#, compression

I am trying to extract files from a folder in C# using `ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipFile, extractPath);` as explained here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh485723(v=vs.110).aspx in the example section. Its keep throwing an exception "Extracting Zip entry would have resulted in a file outside the specified destination directory." For this exception Microsoft is saying "this might happen if the entry name contains parent directory accessors." I have no idea what does that mean. I have tried changing zipFile, extractPath to completely different places but still no idea what to do.

Comment: Pretty unusual.  Send the .zip file back, you don't want it.

Comment: I figured one thing that there must be a difference between a folder downloaded from DropBox as zip and the zip folder we create. Because this line of code works fine when I give it the zip file that I created and throw above error when I use folder downloaded from dropbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is likely with the zip file, not with your code.  It is possible to create a zip file with relative positions upwards from the directory in which the zip file is being created, for instance:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\zip.EXE" d:\bar.zip ..\*
```

In which case the zip file actually contains "..\" in the relative path information.

It sounds as though `ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory()` is refusing to unzip such zip files, perhaps for security reasons (I.e. a web server unzipping such a file might find itself overwriting files outside the target directory!)  In fact, if I try to open such a zip file using ExtractAll in the windows shell, I get this error:

[image]

You can at least open such files in [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org) to see if this is happening (and in fact 7zip will extract files from the crazy zip file I created with the command above.)

If, when creating the zip file, you change directory to the parent directory, rather than zipping the parent directory, then all should be well.  I.e.:

```
pushd .. & "C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\zip.EXE" d:\bar5.zip * & popd
```

will create a zip file that Windows likes, because `zip` will be creating a zip file relative to the *current directory* at the moment it is run.

Comment: you are right! zip file was the culprit. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

I believe the parent directory accessors are the "." and ".." characters in the path to specify the current and previous directories respectively. Do you have any of them in your `extractPath` like `..\Folder`?